# Javascript get lines when string has plain text escape sequence in it, like "hello\nworld"

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Lets say I have a string like this

```
const str = `{FOO: "Hello\nWorld"}
{"BAR": "Nice\nTo\nMeet\nYou"}`
```

when I do `str.split("\n")`
the output is

```
Array(6) [ "{FOO: \"Hello", "World\"}", "\"BAR\": \"Nice", "To", "Meet", "You\"}" ]
```

that's expected, but I want to get an output like this:

```
Array(2) [ '{FOO: "Hello\nWorld"}', '{"BAR": "Nice\nTo\nMeet\nYou"}' ]
```

Edit: I will always have a } after a "invisible" newline

Comment: You cannot, without modifying the original string to use `\\n` instead of `\n`

Comment: There's no difference between the newlines created with the escape sequence and the literal newlines.

Comment: I understand, my regex is poor, but I think for my specific case like in the example I showed you may be able to know if the \n is between the " "

Comment: Either escape or use `String.raw\`your\ntext\``.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the JavaScript string is concerned, there is no difference between these:

```
var a = `
`;
var b = `\n`;
console.log(a === b); // outputs true
```

In other words, there's no difference between the string in your post, and these two:

```
const str2 = `{FOO: "Hello\nWorld"}\n{"BAR": "Nice\nTo\nMeet\nYou"}`
const str3 = `{FOO: "Hello
World"}\n{"BAR": "Nice
To
Meet
You"}`
```

So there's no way to differentiate between these once they're in a JavaScript string. However, if you have an NDJSON file like this:

```ndjson
{"FOO": "Hello\nWorld"}
{"BAR": "Nice\nTo\nMeet\nYou"}
```

... and you load the contents of that file into JSON as a string, you end up with a string that's equivalent to this:

```
const str = `{FOO: "Hello\\nWorld"}
{"BAR": "Nice\\nTo\\nMeet\\nYou"}`
```

... which means your current code should work just fine.

If, on the other hand, your file looks like this:

```
{FOO: Hello
World"}
{"BAR": "Nice
To
Meet
You"}
```

... then you're dealing with a domain-specific language and the only reliable way to get what you want from it is to write your own parser that takes into account things like:

- close-braces inside of strings (`{"Hello}\nWorld"}`)
- escaped double-quotes (`{"Hello World\"}\n"}`)
- any other oddity that the source might have (shouldn't `FOO` have quotes around it?)

Comment: I am getting a raw text response from a server, and the server is not escaping / using the correct content type. so it is just plain text.

Comment: @AlexMortez: That sounds like NDJSON. But if the plain text you're getting back from the server literally has `\n` in the string, then the JSON representation of that would be `\\n`, so your current split code should work just fine.

Comment: @AlexMortez: See my update. You may want to provide details about the _actual input_ you're receiving, rather than an example that doesn't quite capture it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) `/\{[^}]+\}/g`:

```js
const str = `{FOO: "Hello\nWorld"}
{"BAR": "Nice\nTo\nMeet\nYou"}`

const result = str.match(/\{[^}]+\}/g)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: @AlexMortez this assumes you'll always have a new line only after the `}` character, is it true? If so you should probably edit your question so it's clear what is its scope.

Comment: @Kaiido it's true & I edited it

Comment: @AlexMortez: It also assumes there will never be a string that has a closing brace followed by a new line. What systems do you have in place to prevent users from entering "Hello}\nWorld"?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior okay, I see, It does not work as I thought.